# Python Keyboard module - Exit blocking read event function

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard, python-multithreading

Hello,
I have the below code that corrects user input and I want to exit the blocking function keyboard.read_event when the control is returned from the correction thread.
The whole program works well but I cannot exit immediately after the corrector thread is finished (the program waits for key press).
I tried using a custom Exception for interrupting the keyboard.read_event function, but I didn't manage to make it work.

```
import keyboard
import threading
import time

class Interrupt_Custom_Exception(Exception):
   """Base class for other exceptions"""
   pass

#########################################################
def delete_and_write(times_to_delete, word_to_write):
    print("------------Deleting & Rewrite Started---")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("------------Deleting & Rewrite Ended---")
    # simulate deletion and rewrite
    #**here I tried the raise Interrupt_Custom_Exception and tried to catch it at the code in the class, but didn't work**


def write_the_suppressed_string(string):
    keyboard.write(string)
#########################################################

class keyboard_monitor(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,thread_name, threadID, word_typed,  keyboard_suppress, counter_for_key_pressed):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.name = thread_name
        self.threaID = threadID
        self.fstring = word_typed
        self.counter_for_key_presses = counter_for_key_pressed
        self.suppressed = keyboard_suppress
        self.temp = ""

    def stop(self):
        self._is_running = False

    def run(self):

        if (self.suppressed is False):

            while(True):

                event = keyboard.read_event(suppress = self.suppressed)

                if (event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN):

                    if (event.name == "space"):

                        suppressed_monitor = keyboard_monitor("suppressed_monitor", 2, self.fstring, True, self.counter_for_key_presses)
                        suppressed_monitor.start()
                        suppressed_monitor.join()

                        print("RETURNED TO MAIN MONITOR")
                        self.counter_for_key_presses = 0
                        self.fstring = ""
                    elif (event.name in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
                        self.fstring = ''.join([self.fstring, event.name])
                        self.counter_for_key_presses += 1

        elif (self.suppressed is True):

            def listen_to_keyboard():
                event = keyboard.read_event(suppress=self.suppressed)
                # **here is where the program waits and don't continue when the correction thread is  finished.**
                if (event.event_type == keyboard.KEY_DOWN):
                    print("---KEYS PRESSED WHILE SUPPRESSED = {}---".format(event.name))
                    if (event.name in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"):
                        self.fstring = ''.join([self.fstring, event.name])
                        self.counter_for_key_presses += 1

            try:

                #########################################################
                # INITIALY CORRECTING THE WORD PASSED FROM THE NORMAL KEY MONITOR
                self.temp = self.fstring
                self.fstring = ""
                thread_delete_and_rewrite = threading.Thread(
                    target = delete_and_write, args=(self.counter_for_key_presses, self.temp))
                thread_delete_and_rewrite.start()
                # raise Interrupt_Custom_Exception

                #########################################################

                print("-BEFORE WHILE LOOP-")
                while(thread_delete_and_rewrite.is_alive() is True): # **this works ok but if the control enters the listen_to_keyboard function waits there until a key is pressed. I want somehow to stop this manually and continue the code after this while**
                    print("--ENTERING THE WHILE LOOP--")
                    listen_to_keyboard()
                    print("----EXITING THE WHILE LOOP----\n")            
            except Interrupt_Custom_Exception:
                print("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!CAUGHT IT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!")
                print("----EXITING THE WHILE LOOP----\n")

            print("------BEFORE FINAL WRITE------")

            if (self.fstring != ""):
                thread_write = threading.Thread(
                                target = write_the_suppressed_string, args=(self.fstring, ))
                thread_write.start()
                thread_write.join()
            print("SUPPRESSED ENDED")
            self._is_running = False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    kb_not_suppressed = keyboard_monitor("not_suppressed_monitor", 1, "", False, 0)
    kb_not_suppressed.start()
    kb_not_suppressed.join()
```

Any idea on how to exit this blocking function would be very very useful.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible unless you find some `keyboard.read_event` that has a timeout, or does a non-blocking check if there's a event. I haven't found any of those in `keyboard` module ;/

A big workaround would be to `keyboard.press` in case you want to exit. Not sure if you can detect if it's not from the user. It's up to you if it's acceptable.